# Exactly matching search result pages for synonymous query terms in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, search, sharepoint-2010, keyword, enterprise

i work with sharepoint 2010 search optimization and I was wondering if there's a way to make query terms exactly synonymous with each other.

The option I found in the search center settings is a little off target with mandatory creation of a best bet. I want, for example, the search results pages for 'IE' and 'Internet Explorer' to be exactly the same.

Any idea how to go about it? thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You need to define a thesaurus file. It's laborious, but can be done.

There's a good post about it here:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/enterprisesearch/archive/2008/09/23/how-to-customize-the-thesaurus-in-sharepoint-search-and-search-server.aspx

Comment: You're right this does look cumbersome but i think it is what I'm looking for. Thanks a ton Andy!!

Answer (score 0):

The thesaurus is probably the way to go. Remember though that the thing with any version of Sharepoint Search except FAST is that synonyms are one way only, meaning when someone enters IE, it is a synonym for Internet Explorer. Internet Explorer is not a synonym for IE. (depending on which way you defined it of course). This means that any query for IE will include all content related to both and a query for Internet Explorer will render results for Internet Explorer content only.